# How does jQuery cause execution of JS code found inside script tags returned within an AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What exactly is the **magic** that jQuery does that causes execution of JS code inside script tags found inside an AJAX response?

For example, when not using jQuery AJAX like below, I see use of `eval()` is frequently described as as a way to do this:

- [Calling a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response)
- [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

So `eval` does the magic of code execution in those cases.  I do not see the use of `eval` in jQuery AJAX calls.

**jQuery Magic**

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'process_form.php',
        data : $("#form").serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            $("#main_page").load('main_page.php');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here jQuery sets up an event (form submit) to where clicking submit on a form submits the form and then it AJAX-loads the DIV with information returned from `main_page.php` (That page contains update information + JS + jQuery) into `main_page` div element.  But, not just that.

*It also triggers and runs and executes any JS/jQuery code located inside the script tags of the ajax-loaded data without any use of eval that I can see*

**Question:  How does it do that?**

**Note:**

I am using some 3rd party proprietary AJAX library, which properly loads up the response into `main_page` div but then it *does not* run any JS/jQuery.

**Note 2:**

to be clear, there is no problem at all with the jQuery code in question.  It works and *executes* whatever JS was in the `main_page.php`.  The proprietary AJAX library that I use loads up the page but does not execute any AJAX in it.  I want to figure out what makes it not execute the code when jQuery executes the code.

**3rd Paty Library that does not trigger script tag code execution**

Delving into the library I see this:

```
http_req.open(method, url, true);

if (method == "POST") {
    http_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http_req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", post_str.length);
    http_req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http_req.send(post_str);
} else if (method == "GET") {
    http_req.send(null);
}
```

Library is called using something like this event on a submit button:

```
onclick="process_form(..., url, 'main_page'...)"
```

It also has this:

```
var responseObj = new getObject(response);
responseObj.obj.innerHTML = http_req.responseText;
```

Full code surrounding the above:

```
http_req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http_req.readyState == 4 || http_req.readyState == "complete") {
        if (response != "" && redir == "") {
            if (response == "document") {
                document.write(http_req.responseText);
            } else {

                //Update of innerHTML (but without triggering execution)
                //of code found in <script> tags of http_req.responseText
                responseObj.obj.innerHTML = http_req.responseText;
                loadingObj.style.display = "none";
            }

        } else if (response != "" && redir != "" && response != "over") {
            load_page(redir, "", response, "GET", "");
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that it updates `innerHTML` but does not ...

- add it into the DOM?
- do `eval`?
- do the **magic**?

What is the magic that jQuery possesses that the above library skips out?
Is there a way I can fix the library to cause it to execute the code found in response script tag?

Comment: There's no magic (and even better, no `eval()`) involved here. The `success` property is simply assigned the *reference* to the anonymous function. When jQuery determines that the request worked, it then calls the function in that reference.

Comment: after jQuery calls anonymous function in the `success` reference, why does it not just load the raw data and stop?  Why does it proceed to parse out the data and run any JS/jQuery it finds in there?

Comment: That's because by default it detects the format of the response and deserialises it, if necessary. You can stop that behaviour if you prefer by setting `dataType: 'text'`

Comment: "does not execute any AJAX in it." AJAX isn't code, it's a technology for communicating with a server. Do you mean the Javascript in `main_page.php` runs when loaded with jQuery and not with your 3rd party library? This question makes very little sense.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it does not execute any JS/jQuery inside of it.   And yes.  jQuery runs the JavaScript, when my 3rd party library does not.

Comment: @Dennis Okay, then jQuery isn't running that code. What it's doing is adding all of the HTML from `main_page.php` into `#main_page`, just like if you wrote the HTML there yourself. So because script tags are added to the DOM, they're executed. Your 3rd party library must not be adding it to the DOM correctly or at all.

Comment: ^ ah I like that.  Perhaps this is the case.  I did not know there was this addition being done on jQuery side (nor how it does it)

Comment: @MikeC interesting... since `#main_page` div is already part of the DOM of the page, before the AJAX call.  After the successful AJAX call, does jQuery first remove it and then re-add it back?

Comment: @Dennis No, it just removes everything *inside* of it then adds them back.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that this callback is executed in your browser, right? This have nothing to do with your server response. It only executes WHEN your server gives you data back.

You can see proper documentation on XHR here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: when I use a custom 3rd party AJAX library, I use an `onclick` event which calls a function that processes the form and returns a response, and loads up a new 'updated' page into the `main_page` div.  But in this case, server response does not execute when server gives me data back.  Why it does not execute is the missing magic that I seek.  jQuery seems to have it when the library I use does not.

Comment: @Dennis Are you asking why your jQuery code doesn't refresh the page?

Comment: well, no ... inner div inside the page is reloaded, but any JS inside of it is not executed.

Comment: @Dennis The page shouldn't refresh since you're doing `return false`. You are, however, asynchronously loading content from `main_page.php` and putting it into a div with an ID of `main_page`.

Comment: correct.  I mean the `div` inside the page is refreshed/reloaded via AJAX.  The page itself stays put and is not reloaded.  -- corrected the above

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understand your question correctly:

```
 success : function(data) {
        $("#main_page").load('main_page.php');
    }
```

this is the so called "success handler" - it is an event listener, that waits until the http response is received from the server. Javascript works a lot with callback functions which means, you call an action (like the ajax request) and once finished, it calls back another (often anonymous) function.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: Yes.  But why does it not just "load up the page into the div and then stop (and not execute any JS inside)".  How does it execute the JS in that div after load?  For example, imagine there are 30 modal boxes with different IDs that all have to be 'activated'?  I have a situation to where in my case the DIV is loaded but modal boxes ("The JS") are not activated and are just rendered one after the other.  Where activating them mean they will be hidden until a proper event is triggered later.  If that makes sense..

Comment: imagine that you can receive any string from the request, so it could be `<div id="test">hello world</div>` as well as `<script>alert('java')</script>`. I am not 100% sure, but i guess that this alert should be executed just like if you'd called it inside of the success handler function: `success: function(data){ alert(data); }`

Comment: no sorry i am wrong - you need to call `eval()` to execute! `success: function(data){ alert(eval(data)); }` - so far data is javascript code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656558/execute-javascript-function-on-a-page-sent-via-ajax-response

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses its own [Deferred's](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) to implement callbacks including for its ajax implementation. See the code here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js